# Django raw raises relation does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql

i am getting a relation does not exist and I cant find a solution.

```
error:relation "sales_Oeslshstsql" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "sales_Oeslshstsql
```

(app name is sales)

model:

```
class Oeslshstsql(models.Model):
    hst_prd = models.SmallIntegerField()
    hst_year = models.SmallIntegerField()
    cus_no = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    item_no = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    .....

    a4glidentity = models.IntegerField(db_column='A4GLIdentity', primary_key = True)  

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'OESLSHST_SQL'

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.hst_year)
```

---

View:

```
def sales(request):
    #sales_list = Oeslshstsql.objects.all().order_by('hst_year','hst_prd').reverse()
    s = Oeslshstsql.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM "sales_Oeslshstsql"')
    sales_list = s

    return render(request,'saleslist.html',{'sales_list':sales_list})
```

The error is raised when `s` is evaluated. I tried switching cases in the select and messed with migrations no luck.

I am migrating an existing app to Django using a postgres backend, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably not the problem but have you installed pyscopy? If you're new to Python and Django it is necessary to use Postgres with Python. There are other options but it is the most popular.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#db-table seems your tablename in query is wrong

Comment: changing to  did fix original error (thought i did try it earlier though) but now i get" Raw query must include the primary key" error  ... ??

Comment: I have psycopg2 installed.

Comment: @Cstrasser you should add the primary key as id see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#mapping-query-fields-to-model-fields

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
s = Oeslshstsql.objects.raw('SELECT a4glidentity as id, ... ,  FROM "OESLSHST_SQL"')
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#db-table seems your tablename in query is wrong

edit: you should add the primary key as id see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#mapping-query-fields-to-model-fields

Answer (score 0):

Hi I  had the same issue migrating an existing app to 1.11. The only solution I  found was ....

1. Clear all all files from the app's migrations dir leaving only the **init**.py file
2. Make sure that the admin.py file is empty
3. Run `manage.py makemigrations`
4. Run `manage.py sqlmigrate <app_label> 0001`
5. copy the sql output
6. using pgAdminIII select "Execute arbitrary SQL queries"
7. Paste and execute the SQL statements in pgAdminIII

This was the only solution I could find, bit of a hack true, but worked. Hope it helps.This would also work via psql terminal I suppose, but I used pgAdmin